# Java: synchronized over pointers to objects?

Tags: java, list, synchronization, synchronized

Let's say I have `list_a` which I need to have synchronized access to.
Now if I define a pointer to this object `list_A`

```
List<...> list_a=Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<JmDNS>());
List<...> list_A=list_a;
```

can I synchronize over `List_A` and assume that access to `List_a` is synchronized? This is because `list_a` is from a different class with private access and it is being accessed from within that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they reference the same object which is a synchronized list.

**Note**

I assume that you are aware that you synchronize only method calls on the list by using synchronized list.

Suppose you have something like this:

```
if (list_A.size() > 0) {
   Object element = list_A.remove(0);
}
```

Using a synchronized list alone does not make this a thread safe sequence of operations, because two threads can simultaneously evaluate the `if` condition to `true`, and then both can try to remove the first element from the list.

You can solve it this way:

```
synchronized(list_A) {
    if (list_A.size() > 0) {
       Object element = list_A.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I know and that was the problem here. if the elements in `List_a` are to be iterated, I still need to synchronize over it, which is why I was curious as to whether I could `synchronized(List_A)` instead.

Comment: @ShS Ok, then my note was actually the answer to the question. :) I edited the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

> can I synchronize over List_A and assume that access to List_a is synchronized?

No. You need not to synchronize `List_A` again. Because `List_A` already pointing to `list_a` which is synchronized.

```
List<...> list_A=list_a;
```

That line alone means, you are not creating any new object, just referencing an existing one.

Comment: The problem is that I still need to synchronize over a synchronizedList if I want to iterate over it, so it's not "already synchronized".

Comment: @ShS Why ? Why you want to synchronized again ? No need.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29: "Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing list is accomplished through the returned list.
It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it."

Answer (score 0):

You need not to  synchronize list_A again as the reference list_A & list_a are pointing to the same list which is synchronized.

But you need to synchronize around the list when you iterate it.
A common use case with a synchronised collection like this is to add to the list in multiple threads, but to iterate it only at the end when all tasks have complete.

If you are iterating after all the updating threads are done than don't worry about synchronization that time.

Comment: From the SynchronizedList's documentation: "Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing list is accomplished through the returned list.

It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it: ".

So I think I still need to synchronize over list_a object.

Comment: @ShS updated my answer hope, able to address your query.

Comment: That's the problem, I currently have a while loop that checks if the list has been filled with at least say 10 elements, if yes, then proceed with doing something next and if not, the thread is put to sleep for a little while to be checked again. So, I am iterating this while background threads are manipulating it. By the way, is there a more efficient way of achieving this? I guess I could use `ListChangeListener`'s `wasUpdated()` and check if I the list now has the minimum size, but that might be limit the access of those background threads, right?

Comment: anyway nvm that's apparently from javafx.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using java.util.Vector ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

just quoting:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the vector is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future. The Enumerations returned by the elements method are not fail-fast.